# slider menu bugs and active button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a slider menu which opens from left to right.
I have created an arrow button separate from the menu and the menu itself which is a white rectangle which appear from left to right.

I have a couple of problems:

1. first the arrow don't look like part of the slider menu which is separate from all the other components.
2. I have a strange bug that when I open the menu, it first can appear in different sizes according to content height, then the height changes in the same manner.
3. When I open the slider menu, the upper menu's height get extended with no reason.

Any clue how to fix this bugs or make this menu look prettier?

The code to the menu is the following:

```js
  $(function () {
        $("#arrow_btn").click(function () {
            $("#navbar").toggleClass('active');
            $("#upper_left_menu").toggleClass('open_left_menu');
            console.log("look for arrow btn element");
            console.log("upper_left_menu", $("#upper_left_menu"));
            console.log('$("#navbar")', $("#navbar"));
        });

       $(".project_item").click(function (event) {
           var list = $(this).siblings();
           var i = $(this).find('i');
           $(list).toggleClass('closed_nested_list');
           if ($(i).hasClass('fa-plus')) {
               $(i).removeClass('fa-plus');
               $(i).addClass('fa-minus');
           } else {
               $(i).addClass('fa-plus');
               $(i).removeClass('fa-minus');
           }
           console.log('traverse over all project items');
           console.log('i', i);
           console.log('list', list);
       });

    });
```

```css
 .arrow {
     color: gray;
     font: bold 11px "Helvetica";
     padding: 2px;
     text-decoration: none;
     -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
     -moz-border-radius: 20px;
     border-radius: 20px;
    }

    .arrow:after {
     background: gray;
     color: #FFF;
     content: ">";
     display: inline-block;
     font: bold 11px "Georgia";
     height: 25px;
     line-height: 25px;
     margin-left: 2px;
     text-align: center;
     width: 25px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
     -moz-border-radius: 20px;
     border-radius: 20px;
    }
    .arrow:hover:after{
      background: #1679C6;
    }
    .upper_menu{
        position:relative;
        display:block;
        background-color: #F2F6F7;
        width: 100%;
        height: 20%;
    }
    .open_left_menu{
        background-color:white;
        width:30px;
        height:30px;
        box-shadow: 4px 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
        -webkit-transition: all 600ms ease;
        -moz-transition: all 600ms ease;
        -ms-transition: all 600ms ease;
        -o-transition: all 600ms ease;
        transition: all 600ms ease;
    }
    #upper_left_menu{
    }
     #upper_right_menu{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        right: 0px;
    }

     #exclamation-triangle,
     #envelope{
         font-size: 24px;
     }

     .warning,
     .email{
         margin: 10px;
     }

     #exclamation_notifications_count,
     #email_notifications_count{
         padding-left: 5px;
     }

 #navbar {
        position: absolute;
        left: -16em;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: white;
        box-shadow: 4px 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-top: 26px;
        animation:  10s;
      }

    #navbar ul {
        width: 224px;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 1em;
    }

    /* hovering */
    #navbar, #navbar * {
        -webkit-transition: all 600ms ease;
        -moz-transition: all 600ms ease;
        -ms-transition: all 600ms ease;
        -o-transition: all 600ms ease;
        transition: all 600ms ease;
    } 

    #navbar.active {
        left: 0px;
    }
    
    .nested_list{
        display:inline-block;
        visibility:visible;
    }
    .closed_nested_list{
        display:none;
    }

    .project_item{
        font-family:'Segue UI', Calibri, arial, verdana, sans-serif;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="upper_menu">
    <div id="upper_left_menu">
        <span id="arrow_btn" class="arrow"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="upper_right_menu">
        <a href="#" class="warning"><i id="exclamation-triangle" class=" fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i><span id="exclamation_notifications_count">2</span></a>
        <a href="#" class="email"><i id="envelope" class=" fa fa-envelope-o"></i><span id="email_notifications_count">5</span></a>
    </div>
</nav>
<nav id="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li class="project_container">
            <span class="project_item" >
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>  
                FDR Project
            </span>
            <ul id="listOne" class="nested_list closed_nested_list">
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="../images/engine-lighting-bolt.png" />     Unit01</li>
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="../images/engine-lighting-bolt.png" />     Unit02</li>
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="../images/engine-lighting-bolt.png" />     Unit03</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="project_container">
            <span class="project_item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>  Niagara Project</span>
            <ul id="listTwo" class="nested_list closed_nested_list">
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="../images/engine-lighting-bolt.png" />     Unit01</li>
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="../images/engine-lighting-bolt.png" />     Unit02</li>
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="../images/engine-lighting-bolt.png" />     Unit03</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="project_container">
            <span class="project_item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>  Jarvis Plant</span>
            <ul id="listThree" class="nested_list closed_nested_list">
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="../images/engine-lighting-bolt.png" />     Unit01</li>
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="../images/engine-lighting-bolt.png" />     Unit02</li>
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="../images/engine-lighting-bolt.png" />     Unit03</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="project_container">
            <span class="project_item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>  Jarvis Plant</span>
            <ul id="listFour" class="nested_list closed_nested_list">
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="../images/engine-lighting-bolt.png" />     Unit01</li>
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="../images/engine-lighting-bolt.png" />     Unit02</li>
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="../images/engine-lighting-bolt.png" />     Unit03</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you can use font awosone icon and then its will look much better
2. when you open the slider its append a scroll on the right i think that its why it's look odd

**edit1**

in you `side-nav` you css is `margin-top:26px`. change it to `5%` and the height of the nav to `height:95%`

Comment: any suggestion how to fix the second issue?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```js
$(function () {
        $("#arrow_btn").click(function () {
            $("#navbar, .upper_menu").toggleClass('active');
            $("#upper_left_menu").toggleClass('open_left_menu');
            console.log("look for arrow btn element");
            console.log("upper_left_menu", $("#upper_left_menu"));
            console.log('$("#navbar")', $("#navbar"));
        });

       $(".project_item").click(function (event) {
           var list = $(this).siblings();
           var i = $(this).find('i');
           $(list).toggleClass('closed_nested_list');
           if ($(i).hasClass('fa-plus')) {
               $(i).removeClass('fa-plus');
               $(i).addClass('fa-minus');
           } else {
               $(i).addClass('fa-plus');
               $(i).removeClass('fa-minus');
           }
           console.log('traverse over all project items');
           console.log('i', i);
           console.log('list', list);
       });

    });
```

```css
.arrow {
  color: gray;
  font: bold 11px "Helvetica";
  padding: 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.arrow:after {
  background: gray;
  color: #FFF;
  content: ">";
  display: inline-block;
  font: bold 11px "Georgia";
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.arrow:hover:after {
  background: #1679C6;
}

.upper_menu {
  position: absolute;      
  display: block;
  background-color: #F2F6F7;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#upper_left_menu {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 600ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 600ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 600ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 600ms ease;
  transition: all 600ms ease;
}

.open_left_menu {
  margin-left: 256px;
}

#upper_right_menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

#exclamation-triangle,
#envelope {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.warning,
.email {
  margin: 10px;
}

#exclamation_notifications_count,
#email_notifications_count {
  padding-left: 5px;
}

#navbar {
  position: absolute;
  left: -16em;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 4px 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  animation: 10s;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#navbar ul {
  width: 224px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
}


/* hovering */

#navbar,
#navbar * {
  -webkit-transition: all 600ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 600ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 600ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 600ms ease;
  transition: all 600ms ease;
}

#navbar.active {
  left: 0px;
}

.nested_list {
  display: inline-block;
  visibility: visible;
}

.closed_nested_list {
  display: none;
}

.project_item {
  font-family: 'Segue UI', Calibri, arial, verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="upper_menu">
    <div id="upper_left_menu">
        <span id="arrow_btn" class="arrow"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="upper_right_menu">
        <a href="#" class="warning"><i id="exclamation-triangle" class=" fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i><span id="exclamation_notifications_count">2</span></a>
        <a href="#" class="email"><i id="envelope" class=" fa fa-envelope-o"></i><span id="email_notifications_count">5</span></a>
    </div>
</nav>
<nav id="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li class="project_container">
            <span class="project_item" >
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>  
                FDR Project
            </span>
            <ul id="listOne" class="nested_list closed_nested_list">
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="../images/engine-lighting-bolt.png" />     Unit01</li>
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="../images/engine-lighting-bolt.png" />     Unit02</li>
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="../images/engine-lighting-bolt.png" />     Unit03</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="project_container">
            <span class="project_item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>  Niagara Project</span>
            <ul id="listTwo" class="nested_list closed_nested_list">
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="../images/engine-lighting-bolt.png" />     Unit01</li>
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="../images/engine-lighting-bolt.png" />     Unit02</li>
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="../images/engine-lighting-bolt.png" />     Unit03</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="project_container">
            <span class="project_item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>  Jarvis Plant</span>
            <ul id="listThree" class="nested_list closed_nested_list">
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="../images/engine-lighting-bolt.png" />     Unit01</li>
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="../images/engine-lighting-bolt.png" />     Unit02</li>
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="../images/engine-lighting-bolt.png" />     Unit03</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="project_container">
            <span class="project_item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>  Jarvis Plant</span>
            <ul id="listFour" class="nested_list closed_nested_list">
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="../images/engine-lighting-bolt.png" />     Unit01</li>
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="../images/engine-lighting-bolt.png" />     Unit02</li>
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="../images/engine-lighting-bolt.png" />     Unit03</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: All bugs are fixxed I think. :)

Answer (score 0):

After I go with niza's solutions I got a strange case that the arrow is go far from the menu and there is a space between the menu and the arrow:
[image]

Comment: Which browser? I haven't.

Comment: I run it on chrome browser

Comment: The postion of the arrow button is determined with a `margin-left:256px`. The fixed width of the navbar.

Comment: I fixed it, change the value to a lower own. thanks you are the best.